# C# : No overload for method 'Equals' takes '4' arguments

Tags: c#

I have my assert as below .

```
Assert.True(jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString().Equals(DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString(), "AdvertisedStartTime didn't match Json ", jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString(), DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString()));
```

and it is throwing an error

> No overload for method 'Equals' takes '4' arguments

Can anyone please help to find what is wrong?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Exactly what it says. You're passing 4 parameters to equals.

Comment: Why are you comparing strings instead of DateTime instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your parens this is it fixed

```
Assert.True(jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString().Equals(DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString()),
    "AdvertisedStartTime didn't match Json ", jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString(),
    DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString());
```

Comment: :- thanks for pointing out parens issue. It solved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

You're posting 4 parameters to string.Equals(), and such a function doesn't exist. At most Equals takes 3 parameters.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Assert.True(
    jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString().Equals(
        DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString(),
        "AdvertisedStartTime didn't match Json ", 
        jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString(), 
        DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString()
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused because this is a HUGE line of code. Break it into multiple lines.

```
var lineStr = jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString();
Assert.True(
    lineStr.Equals(
        DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString(), //1
        "AdvertisedStartTime didn't match Json ", //2
        jsonDataLine[i].AdvertisedStartTime.Value.ToString(), //3
        DateTimeOffset.Parse(sqlNodeList[i]["AdvertisedStartTime"].InnerText).UtcDateTime.ToString() //4
    )
);
```

Clearly now, you're passing four parameters into the Equals function, which is not supported. What are you really trying to test here?